# in node js ,how to set login permission on facebook developer API?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My code is:- .. and they give me error in the "output"
,How can i solve it??

code:

```
var FB=require('fb');
    FB.login(function(response) {
        // handle the response
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
        }
        else {
            FB.login();
        }
    },
    {scope: 'publish_actions',
        return_scopes: true
    });

  Output: FB.login(function(response) {
       ^

    TypeError: FB.login is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vvLocal\Desktop\work\facebook\fbLogin.js:3:4)
```

Comment: Why you are writing the FB authentication code in node ? Checking on node will require an API call, which will authenticate the user using his FB credentials. You can simply check this on UI, thus removing this extra API call. Are you using any framework for UI ?

Comment: You should use passport if you are trying to do login on server side, otherwise use the facebook sdk for javascript. By looking in the documentation of https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk, indeed it's not a function.

Comment: No...i want to run code directlly in node js cmd and get output @rohankangale

Comment: _“i want to run code directlly in node js cmd and get output”_ – that is not possible, resp. makes no sense. FB.login opens a popup in the user’s browser, so that the user can login to your app. Trying to do this server-side makes no sense to  begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {}
var FB = require('fb'),
fb = new FB.Facebook(options);

fb.login(function(response) {
    // handle the response
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log('Logged in.');
    }
    else {
        fb.login();
    }
},
{scope: 'publish_actions',
    return_scopes: true
});
```

Try that even I didn't test ;)